# Stop fragment Re-Creation in BottomNavigation using NavGraph

Tags: android, navigation, android-lifecycle, bottomnavigationview, android-viewmodel

I have multiple fragments like **Dashboard**,**Notifications** and **Profile** in Bottom Navigation. I am using NavGraph- NavController to control the fragments.

> I want to save the state of previous fragment.

I don't want to call my API's again on Switching between fragments. Whenever I switch between fragment it calls onDestroyView of previous fragment and onCreateView of current Fragmnent . That's why all the operation in onCreateView or onViewCreated will call again.

How could I get rid of it. Is there any implementation using **NavGraph** that stop fragment from reCeating

Or is there a way to don't call those API's again . I mean to retatin the UIState.

***For example:***
The user is on **Map** fragment and he search some location on Google Map and moves to the next fragment **Dashboard**

I have tried using

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
   lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
        Log.v("LifeCycleState","launchWhenCreated")
   }
}
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
         Log.v("LifeCycleState","launchWhenCreated in viewLifeCycleOwner")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you only want to use NavGraph?

Comment: Yes our priority is through NavGraph

Answer (score 0):

You've to follow multi navigations graph concept.

Create separate graphs for the bottom nav icon based. Ex Home, History and Account So you've to create 3 graphs and include in one graph.

Like this

```
<navigation
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@+id/home">

<include app:graph="@navigation/home"/>
<include app:graph="@navigation/history"/>
<include app:graph="@navigation/account"/>
```

Follow this [sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample)

Comment: I have tried but it isn't working . It's same as before.

Comment: I used it's working fine... May be check your code base

Comment: I just cloned the sample you mentioned above but it's not working. It's same as before. . Whenever I switch between fragment it calls onDestroyView of previous fragment and onCreateView of current Fragmnent.

Comment: View goes destroy... But, I believe instance will not clear

Comment: So How we restrict it to don't call api again

Comment: Oh, that's your problem  i gotch u... Just check before calling local data is available if not request initiate the call..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246143/discussion-between-gobu-csg-and-muhammad-ibrahim).

Comment: I tried this, but, in the example, the fragments for history and account tabs are recreated every time, not the views. If you navigate to the home tab, home tab will have the same instance, but view will be recreated every time so you can link rootView and return it if it isn't null in onCreateView. But for history and account tabs, the fragment instances are recreated so the rootView variable is null every time.... I think OP and I are having the same issue. We want other tabs fragments to behave just like the 1st tab fragment.